# Get User-Agent and Timezone in mixins

Tags: node.js, loopback

I am creating a mixin for a model on 'create' hook. I want to access the user-agent and user timezone information.

I tried using LoopBackContext as well. But it is not much of a help as I couldn't find object containing these information.

```
var loopBackContext = require('loopback-context');

module.exports = function Request(Model, options) {
  Model.observe('access', function event(ctx, next) {
   var httpContext = loopBackContext.getCurrentContext();
    //access user-agent and timezone
    next();
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `loopback-context` does not work very reliably, we recommend to pass context via `options` object as explained in https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Using-current-context.html.

The `ctx` argument passed to operation hooks like `access` is yet another type of a context object, see the docs on [Operation hooks](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html).

To access additional request headers, you should also override Model's `createOptionsFromRemotingContext` method, see https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Using-current-context.html#override-createoptionsfromremotingcontext-in-your-model

```js
module.exports = function Request(Model, options) {
  Model.createOptionsFromRemotingContext = function(ctx) {
    const base = this.base.createOptionsFromRemotingContext(ctx);
    return {
      ...base,
      userAgent: req.headers['user-agent'],
      // etc.
    };
  });

  Model.observe('access', function event(ctx, next) {
    const options = ctx.options || {};
    // options contains data created by Model.createOptionsFromRemotingContext
    // but only when invoked via REST API.
    // when called from JavaScript (e.g. from unit-tests), options are exactly
    // as provided by the caller (often undefined).
    const userAgent = ctx.options && ctx.options.userAgent;
    // access user-agent and timezone
    next();
  });
};
```